# Where to find API endpoints in PHP project code

Tags: php

I am working on a frontend project and need to develop a frontend for an already existing backend developed in PHP. I need to extract all the endpoints from the server code and build the frontend accordingly. I need to know where exactly the endpoints are created or listed in PHP code so that I can understand their payload and header requirements.

Comment: If Backend is written with any PHP Framework such as CodeIgniter then check for controllers. You will find all the APIs

Comment: That depends on so many things that there is not a single way to answer your question

Comment: I am not sure what framework is used. Is there any way to identify the framework?

Comment: Wapalizer chrome extension can help with that, It can most of the times identify frameworks and technologies used in website

Comment: As for the endpoints, you should always get some info from the client or have an access to backend documentation

Comment: I have the backend documentation and the endpoint URL is https://sitename.com/api.php Once I open this URL the browser says 404 not found

Comment: it says "To gain access to the endpoints you will first need to be authenticated via the authenticate endpoint and utilize the token in the response to formulate any API requests prior." I tried sending API request using postman to sitename.com/api.php/authenticate, sitename.com/authenticate/ still getting 404 not found

Comment: after checking with https://builtwith.com/ under framework it says php7

Comment: Sounds like the documentation is a bit lacking, unless there's more detail in there which you haven't told us

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.